# Random list generator in increments of 5, which adds up to 100%

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Lets say I have 21 products. A product can be assigned an increment of 5%. Within all the products, their must be a sum of 100%. Allocation of 0% is allowed on products, and so is 100%.

```
sample = ['10', '15', '5', '35', '15', '5', '15', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

I need to find out every combination of of the percentage allocations. I have tried code where I have an array of numbers, 0 - 100 in increments of 5, where I pull a increment as long as the total count does not exceed 100. If it's populating the last element in the array, it populates with 100 - total count.

However the products at the end of the list aren't being allocated anything. I need every possible combination(or as much as I can get) and the way I am doing it now is taking forever as I'm creating a random array and then checking if it already exists. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
def createUniqueArray():
#Array of numbers in increments of 5 
array_of_nums = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]

#Stores sum of 21 numbers needed for array
count_to_hundred = 0

#To store array of 21 numbers
array = []

#Number of products
numProducts = 21

for col in range(numProducts):
    #If not on the last pass
    if col != numProducts:
        #Creating boolean and setting it to false
        suitable_num = False;

        #If already at 100
        if count_to_hundred == 100:
            array.append(0)
        else:
            while suitable_num == False:
                #Find a number between 1 - 20
                value = array_of_nums[random.randint(1,20)]

                if value + count_to_hundred <= 100:
                    #Adding to count
                    count_to_hundred += value
                    #Updating boolean to stop while loop
                    suitable_num = True
                    #Adding value to array
                    array.append(value)          
    else:
        #Getting remaing amount that will add to give 100
        leftOver = 100 - count_to_hundred
        #Add it to array
        array.append(leftOver)
        #Update count
        count_to_hundred = count_to_hundred + leftOver

#Add array to array list
if array not in arrayOfArrays:
    arrayOfArrays.append(array)
```

Comment: hi there! can you add some more details of things you have tried already plus any relevant code? 
It will help understand both the question and solutions you've tried already

Comment: I think there are nearly 138 billion different ways to assign percentages according to your requirements. Even with the best code that will take a while. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192670/n-unlabelled-balls-in-m-labeled-buckets you have 20 'balls' of 5% increments and 21 buckets).

Comment: Yeah i didn't do the math but expected it to be big, I'll cap it off at 10 mill? I'm looking for the optimal allocation within these products.

Comment: Also, this feels like a bin packing problem – you might want to look into algorithms specialized for those. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version above is actually tremendously slow. The following code is at least 13 times faster (for example, `combo(100, 7, 5)` terminated in 19.278904 seconds (06.485530 on another machine), while the `itertools`-based version took *half an hour!* So, it’s **283.843 times** faster!):

```
def combo(Sum, size, step):
    if Sum % step:
        raise ValueError(f'The sum {Sum} must be divisible by step {step}')

    if Sum == 0:
        yield (Sum, ) * size  
    elif size == 2:
        a, b = Sum, 0
        while b != Sum + step:
            yield a, b
            a, b = a - step, b + step
    else:
        fst, lst = Sum, 0
        while lst != Sum:
            for tail in combo(Sum - fst, size - 1, step):
                lst = tail[-1]
                yield (fst, ) + tail
            fst -= step


def test_correctness(x, size, step):  
    import itertools
    Range = range(0, x + step, step)

    it, mine = filter(lambda t: sum(t) == x, itertools.product(Range, repeat=size)),\
        list(combo(x, size, step))

    ok = True
    progress = itertools.cycle('|/-\\')
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(it, reversed(mine))):
        if a != b:
            ok = False
            print(a, b)
        if not (i % 100):
            print(next(progress), end='')

    return ok

def test_speed(x, size, step):
    import itertools, datetime
    Range = range(0, x + step, step)

    tests = {'itertools': filter(lambda t: sum(t) == x, itertools.product(Range, repeat=size)), 'mine': combo(x, size, step)}
    timings = {}

    progress = itertools.cycle('|/-\\')

    for k, val in tests.items():
        print(f'Testing {k}...')

        t_start = datetime.datetime.now()
        for i, _ in enumerate(val):
            if not (i % 100):
                print(next(progress), end='')
        t_end = datetime.datetime.now()
        timings[k] = t_end - t_start
        print(f'\n\t{k} done in {t_end - t_start}')

    coeff = timings['itertools'] / timings['mine']
    print(f'Mine is {coeff:.3f} times faster')
```

Comment: Thank you! have this running now for (100,21,5). Other solution below worked, but got considerably slow after a few hundred thousand runs.

Comment: I ran into a memory error about an hour in. Is there a way to limit the amount of iterations?

Comment: @fent00 if you do not _keep_ all the permutations computed by this algorithm, you won’t run into memory issues soon. To limit the amount of iterations, use `itertools.islice`.

Comment: I put that in, but the thing is that it gathers all the combinations before it returns what limitation I asked for. In AKX's solution, I was able to print out each combination after that individual combination was created, which I hoped I could do with yours. But I guess that's why your code is faster. Maybe I just have to limit it to around 12 products at a time.

Comment: @fent00, no, the whole point of my algorithm is that it _doesn’t_ gather all the combinations before returning them. If you do `for combination in combo(100, 21, 5): print(combo)`, it‘ll generate them on-the-fly and print a combination right after it was generated (actually, don’t do that because your terminal may be unable to do so much output at such insane speed and may freeze; it happened with mine). `itertools.islice` doesn’t save anything in memory either. If you try to save all the combinations in a list, you’ll run out of memory pretty quickly since there are _137'846'528'820_ of them!

Comment: Ahhhh, Thank you. Finally.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` to the rescue! Minding the caveats in the comments (that this may take a while), this will generate the "first" 10 million combinations that sum up to 100%.

```py
import itertools

def generate_combinations(n_products=21, step=5):
    array_of_nums = list(range(0, 100 + step, step))
    for combination in itertools.product(*[array_of_nums for x in range(n_products)]):
        if sum(combination) == 100:
            yield combination

for combo in itertools.islice(generate_combinations(), 10_000_000):
    print(combo)
```

outputs (20 first lines):

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 95)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 90)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 85)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 80)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 75)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 70)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 65)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 60)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 55)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 45)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 40)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 35)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 30)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 20)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 85, 15)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 10)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I wanted.